# SQL Server RDL/RDLC Rendering Report Parameters

Tags: .net, sql-server, rdlc, rdl

I have an RDLC report that has parameters. When I render it on the server side as a SSRS RDL, it includes UI filters for the parameters...but not when I render it in a WinForms app as an RDLC.

Is there a way to do this or is it not supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's supported. You have to build UI yourself to pass the report parameters to your report. [This](http://gotreportviewer.com/) contains a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Is there any way of getting it to use the automatically built filter UI? Or, if not, are there any add-ons you're aware of to automatically and dynamically create a filter UI based on the parameters?

Comment: Hello.I haven't seen any built-in/add on UIs yet. The UI for your parameters is really simple to be built!